# Future does not compile with Success and Failure

Tags: scala

Why this does not compile? I get the following error in the `Success` and `Failure` lines:

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found :
>   scala.util.Success[T] required: Int

And the code:

```
    val future = Future { 1 }
    future.map { 
       case Success(s) => s
       case Failure(f) => 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `map` of a `Future[Int]` expects a function with domain `Int`, but instead you are trying to pass some function with domain `Try[Int]` into it.

The syntactically closest thing that works is `onComplete`:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val future = Future { 1 }
future.onComplete { 
   case Success(s) => s
   case Failure(f) => 0
}
```

However, this is probably not what you want, because the expressions `s` and `0` don't do anything, they are therefore not very interesting callbacks. Instead, you probably either want to `transform` the result:

```
future.transform {
  case Success(s) => Success(s)
  case Failure(f) => Success(0)
}
```

or `recover` from the failure with a `0`:

```
future.recover {
  case f: Exception => 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
 val future = Future {
      1
    }
    future onComplete  {
      case Success(s) => s
      case Failure(f) => 0
    }
```